# Can't get hidden field via $_POST / JInput

Tags: joomla-3.x

I have included a hidden field in my form with this code:

```
<input type="hidden" name="reporter" value="<?php echo $this->item->reportid; ?>" />
```

but I can't access it in my **view.html.php** using this code:

```
$sample = $_POST['reporter'];
```

Is there something I missed? Does this have something to do with Joomla?

UPDATE #1: I used this code below regarding JInput but still I can't get the value for reporter.

```
$input = JFactory::getApplication()->input; 
$test = $input->get('reporter');
```

Comment: You don't use `$_POST` with Joomla, please read the [documentation on how to get post variables](http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput)

Comment: please check my update

Comment: please cross check the form method and action url

Comment: What should I check in the action url @Nick

Comment: Can you access other data from your form? Because the code itself looks fine. I don't think the issue comes from that.

Answer (score 1):

Why you need to access it in your View? Probably the best way to access it is in your Controller.

Anyway please be sure that you post your data right as @Lodder mentioned. Check that your action attribute contains the right component and task. Or you should put some hidden fields in you form to post it to the needed controller and task:

```
<input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_mycomponent" />
<input type="hidden" name="task" value="controller.task" />
```

Comment: Completely agree. First of all why you want to get POST data in view.html.php. Whatever you want to access in this file should get from model itself.